# Phonegap - get if database already exist

Tags: android, database, cordova, exists

I'm using database with Phonegap. I need to know if the database has already been created. I'm trying to avoid the whole creating tables and inserting rows function if the db already exists.

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "FiltersResults", 50000000);

This opens/creates my db, ok, but how do I know if this database already exists?

Answer (score 0):

The `var db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "FiltersResults", 50000000);` checks if you have a database called `myDB` if it exists it opens it. If not, it creates one and opens it. So if you are seeing it creating multiple Databases, below can be two reasons I can think of

- You have more that one window running that url, just Quit the browser completely and open one widow with the URL
- was a knowing UI related bug introduced in Safari 5.1.2, fixed in later versions.

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: I already did, but I need to know is if the DATABASE exists, not the tables. If the database already exists, that means that block of code has already run so, why do it again?

Comment: You open the database once per page load, then manipulate it. You shouldnt need to run window.openDatabase more than once per page anyway, right? So there is no need for checking if it exists.

Comment: @SamThompson: if I go to another page and come back to that page or kill the application and run it again, then how to retrieve the database which is already been created. That is the question.